# Meaning of message "operations coalesced during safepoint"

Tags: java, garbage-collection

A java app runs with the following flag: -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics, and then
produces the following line on the standard output console:

**2 VM operations coalesced during safepoint**

Anyone cares to explain what this mean ?

More generally - is there a Java reference manual somewhere detailling all JVM flags, their use and, most importantly, the expected output, with relevant explanations ?

Comment: Are you aware of Safepoints in general and how they relate to the HotSpot compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of the possible [VM operations](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/1be129f955bf/src/share/vm/runtime/vm_operations.hpp).

This counter is incremented for each subsequent vm operation dealt with while the VM is at a safepoint, i.e. if 1 vm op is processed than it is not incremented, if 2 vm ops are processed it is incremented once, if 3 vm ops are processed it is incremented twice (etc etc).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a specific answer about that message, but can point to [safepoint.cpp](http://xref.jsecurity.net/openjdk-6/langtools/dd/d46/safepoint_8cpp-source.html) in Java 6 source code containing that message.

A [collection of JVM options](http://blogs.oracle.com/watt/resource/jvm-options-list.html) for various versions has been compiled by Joseph D. Mocker

Comment: thanks for the links - the collection of JVM option is a start but still it doesnt actually *explain* how to interpret the associated outputs.

Comment: Thanks @bill-the-lizard for fixing the link.