# Why are there multiple "Total time for which application threads were stopped" logs between two minor GCs

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm running a java application with the following settings:

> -Xms1G -Xmx2G -Xdebug -Xloggc:/usr/local/resin/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:PermSize=150M -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

I thought turning on -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime switch would output how much time the application is stopped each time a GC occurs, but a got multiple lines of logs telling how much time the application is stopped between two minor GCs, like the following logs:

```
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0043330 seconds
Application time: 1410.4236260 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=636 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 38336K, used 34123K [0x00002aaab1a60000, 0x00002aaab43f0000, 0x00002aaab43f0000)
  eden space 34112K, 100% used [0x00002aaab1a60000, 0x00002aaab3bb0000, 0x00002aaab3bb0000)
  from space 4224K,   0% used [0x00002aaab3bb0000, 0x00002aaab3bb2de0, 0x00002aaab3fd0000)
  to   space 4224K,   0% used [0x00002aaab3fd0000, 0x00002aaab3fd0000, 0x00002aaab43f0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1006016K, used 208278K [0x00002aaab43f0000, 0x00002aaaf1a60000, 0x00002aab31a60000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 153600K, used 90763K [0x00002aab31a60000, 0x00002aab3b060000, 0x00002aab3b060000)
122682.024: [GC 122682.024: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 2162688 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 4)
- age   1:       4896 bytes,       4896 total
- age   2:       2272 bytes,       7168 total
: 34123K->10K(38336K), 0.0037720 secs] 242402K->208291K(1044352K), 0.0038540 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
Heap after GC invocations=637 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 38336K, used 10K [0x00002aaab1a60000, 0x00002aaab43f0000, 0x00002aaab43f0000)
  eden space 34112K,   0% used [0x00002aaab1a60000, 0x00002aaab1a60000, 0x00002aaab3bb0000)
  from space 4224K,   0% used [0x00002aaab3fd0000, 0x00002aaab3fd2bf8, 0x00002aaab43f0000)
  to   space 4224K,   0% used [0x00002aaab3bb0000, 0x00002aaab3bb0000, 0x00002aaab3fd0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1006016K, used 208280K [0x00002aaab43f0000, 0x00002aaaf1a60000, 0x00002aab31a60000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 153600K, used 90763K [0x00002aab31a60000, 0x00002aab3b060000, 0x00002aab3b060000)
}
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0044760 seconds
Application time: 317.6313600 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004960 seconds
Application time: 86.5483550 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005090 seconds
Application time: 0.0001400 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001360 seconds
Application time: 46.6827150 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004430 seconds
Application time: 74.2952540 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004940 seconds
Application time: 0.0001300 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001130 seconds
Application time: 0.0001290 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001290 seconds
Application time: 51.1991810 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004860 seconds
Application time: 190.7426760 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004930 seconds
Application time: 0.0000750 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001000 seconds
Application time: 55.4635280 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004900 seconds
Application time: 180.7308270 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005060 seconds
Application time: 60.9953830 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005490 seconds
Application time: 60.9591480 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006410 seconds
Application time: 292.0577720 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=637 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 38336K, used 34122K [0x00002aaab1a60000, 0x00002aaab43f0000, 0x00002aaab43f0000)
  eden space 34112K, 100% used [0x00002aaab1a60000, 0x00002aaab3bb0000, 0x00002aaab3bb0000)
  from space 4224K,   0% used [0x00002aaab3fd0000, 0x00002aaab3fd2bf8, 0x00002aaab43f0000)
  to   space 4224K,   0% used [0x00002aaab3bb0000, 0x00002aaab3bb0000, 0x00002aaab3fd0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1006016K, used 208280K [0x00002aaab43f0000, 0x00002aaaf1a60000, 0x00002aab31a60000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 153600K, used 90763K [0x00002aab31a60000, 0x00002aab3b060000, 0x00002aab3b060000)
124099.341: [GC 124099.341: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 2162688 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 4)
- age   1:      20680 bytes,      20680 total
- age   3:        808 bytes,      21488 total
: 34122K->25K(38336K), 0.0036900 secs] 242403K->208305K(1044352K), 0.0037700 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
Heap after GC invocations=638 (full 2):
 par new generation   total 38336K, used 25K [0x00002aaab1a60000, 0x00002aaab43f0000, 0x00002aaab43f0000)
  eden space 34112K,   0% used [0x00002aaab1a60000, 0x00002aaab1a60000, 0x00002aaab3bb0000)
  from space 4224K,   0% used [0x00002aaab3bb0000, 0x00002aaab3bb6488, 0x00002aaab3fd0000)
  to   space 4224K,   0% used [0x00002aaab3fd0000, 0x00002aaab3fd0000, 0x00002aaab43f0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 1006016K, used 208280K [0x00002aaab43f0000, 0x00002aaaf1a60000, 0x00002aab31a60000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 153600K, used 90763K [0x00002aab31a60000, 0x00002aab3b060000, 0x00002aab3b060000)
}
```

Why are there multiple consecutive lines of "Total time for which the application threads were stopped" and "Application Time" logs between two minor GCs. What is each line of them related to? A GC that is not outputted in detail? or are they not caused by GC?

If I want to know the total time my application stopped for during GCs, should I sum the time in all these logs?

Answer (score 5):

Use `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics` to find out the cause of each safepoint, links in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850514/meaning-of-message-operations-coalesced-during-safepoint) show where to get a full list of what can cause a safepoint to be reached.

Answer (score 1):

This log shows you every reason an application is stopped, not just for GCs.  One way to reduce these is to turn off biased locking (Nothing to do with GCs) ;)

Try

```
-XX:-UseBiasedLocking
```

Comment: i turned off biased locking using -XX:-UseBiasedLocking but i can still see those consecutive logs. I also tried adding the parameter -XX:+TraceBiasedLocking, but I could see no tracing logs whenever biased locking is on of off, is there anything wrong?

Comment: Sounds like something else is causing your application pause.  Its not just the GC. Is a delay of 0.5 ms a problem for your application?

Comment: 0.5ms is not a problem, but I'm wondering if i should count all those lines when i want to know the total application stop time during GCs

Comment: I wouldn't as these stops occur after a GC and often a long time before the next GC.

Comment: Why it is printed in GC log if these lines are not related to GC ?

Comment: @Anton AFAIK, This facility was written for GC but later extended to include non GC pauses, but the name wasn't changed (but perhaps should have been)

Comment: Sounds strange. Also it's not clear what else could cause pauses like that.